# Determine if 2 boxes overlap

Tags: algorithm

I know how to check if 2 rectangles overlap, however, I'm currently working on how to check if 2 boxes are overlapping.

They may have some of the same edge points but they cannot be inside each other or overlapping in the inside. I'm wondering if there is a conditional statement out there that would not make it a O(n^3).

Comment: This may be better suited for a different SE. I'm making a diagram, anyone else feel free to answer.

Comment: Axis aligned boxes or any orientation?

Comment: In your estimation of the complexity of an algorithm, what determines the value of `n` ?

Comment: The value of n is each coordinate point that the box takes up space. For a rectangle, n^2. For a box, n^3 . Yes. they are aligned to the X,Y,Z axis and yes they are rotatable.

Comment: Can you give some examples of two such boxes? The question @harold asked above is quite important, are the boxes aligned or can they be rotated along any orientation?

Comment: @Kay 'Yes. they are aligned to the X,Y,Z axis and yes they are rotatable.' as the answer to 'Axis aligned boxes or any orientation?' seems self-contradictory.

Comment: They can be parallel to any axis. So it won't be a diagonal box or etc.

Comment: Does 'They can be parallel to any axis' mean 'the can be parallel to one axis and not to other two'?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming boxes are aligned rectangles (sides parallel to axes) the answer is straightforward: boxes overlap if they are not separate, and they are separate if one of them is above or below the other or is to the right or to the left from the other.